# How to get Jquery return value to variable?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a small question about jQuery return value, I don't know this possible or not. This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select_company').change(function() {
        var post_company_id     = $(this).val();
        $.post('includes/test.php', { company_id: post_company_id }, function(res) {
            if (res == 1) {
                $('#sucess').show();
                $('#sucess2').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('#sucess2').show();
                $('#sucess').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

this code working fine, what I exactly want.
how can I give response ID as a variable to MYSQL query?

```
$mysql = "SELECT * FROM tb_name WHERE id = $response_id";
```

`$response_id` variable should come from test.php page. Appreciate your great help.

Comment: If I understand, in your php file: `$response_id = $_POST['company_id']`

Comment: Yes, exactly. that is my variable

Comment: So you want to get data **from** your PHP script and put it in to MySQL? What does jQuery have to do with this? jQuery runs in the browser, which is on the opposite side of the PHP to the MySQL server.

Comment: oh! that's clear, I have to send ajax request and get the value from that particular page, OK, I understood,

Answer (score 0):

in your php you can get the id using **insert_id** ( `$mysqli->insert_id;`) from mysqli object after insertion this will give the `current inserted id` which you can use in your `php` or return it to javascript with `encoded data and parse it` on javascript.